# Spring does not see css file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

[Folder hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnFjg.png)
[Browser console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UIXc.png)


Security context:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Spring context:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Import css file in jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />">
```

I have no idea what's wrong... Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: get rid of the `c:url` stuff  and make like href="/resources/style.css" />

Comment: The first, you should check file css from url before add to html.
The second. I have a question for you, why in link import css file, you use `href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />"` instead of `href="resources/style.css" />"`

Comment: In spring context, I hope you save file css in folder: `src/main/webapp/resources/cssfile.css` not in `src/main/resources`

Comment: Can you please try like this:
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
 href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/style.css">

Comment: As you can see on the picture [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnFjg.png)

Comment: I've replaced it but to no avail [log](https://pastebin.com/dfJitQ9G).

Answer (score 0):

Just do like below in `.jsp` (No `/` at before `resources`)

```
<link href="resources/style.css"" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

If it doesn't work for you, try this

```
<link href="<c:url value='resources/style.css' />" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or all full path

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Why resources twice in the second example?

Comment: @Wojkek: What does it log?

Comment: @Wojtek Seem like Spring Security still treats your css file as normal request. Could you provide your configuration.

Comment: @nguyentaijs [security context](https://pastebin.com/MxSUs2qR) [spring context](https://pastebin.com/F3UAXZsX)

Comment: @Wojtek what's the request path of: `filmApp.Test.test()`

Comment: I removed a class responsible for "filmApp.Test.test()" request and it works... But why?  Thank you nguyentaijs!

Comment: There is nothing special in [Test](https://pastebin.com/7GQjDtCW) class.

Comment: @Wojtek I'm not sure what's behind the scenes, somehow, request for `resourses/style.css` take `test()` as handler method